# Homotopy groups of connected components

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a (surjective if it helps) map of simplicial commutative monoids such that the induced map on homotopy groups $\pi_n(X,1)\to \pi_n(Y,1)$ is an isomorphism for all $n\geq 0$. Let $x\in X$. Is $\pi_n(X,x)\to \pi_n(X,f(x))$ necessarily an isomorphism? (I don't even know if homotopy groups with basepoint in different connected components of a simplicial commutative monoid can be non-isomorphic).

Comment: $X=S^1\cup\{0\}$ is a simplicial commutative monoid under complex multiplication, right? Yet components have different homotopy groups. Also, to be clear: $f$ is assumed to be a monoid homomorphism? Or just continuous?

Comment: $f$ is a homomorphism of simplicial monoids, not just of simplicial sets.

Comment: Anyway the direct counterexample is $M$ is any simplicial connected monoid with nontrivial fundamental group (e.g. $M=S^1$) and you artificially add new identity $X=M\sqcup\{*\}$ and put $f:X\to \{*\}$ the constant map. It induces isomorphisms on $x=*$ but not on $x\neq *$.

Comment: @freakish: That doesn't quite work since it won't induce an isomorphism on $\pi_0$.

Comment: Thank you anyway for the first comment.

Comment: @A.G if you want isomorphism on $\pi_0$ then artificially add neutral element on the right side as well. Although it is no longer surjective then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $A$ be any connected simplicial commutative semigroup, and let $X=A\sqcup\{*\}$ with the monoid structure such that $*$ is the identity.  Let $B$ be another connected simplicial commutative semigroup and $Y=B\sqcup\{*\}$ similarly.  Then any (surjective) homomorphism $A\to B$ induces a (surjective) homomorphism $f:X\to Y$, which is an isomorphism on all homotopy groups based at the identity.  However, $f$ is not an isomorphism on homotopy groups based vertices in $A$ unless the original map $A\to B$ was a weak equivalence.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.